# Ionic - Error: Cannot find module 'android-versions'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When a try to run

```
ionic run android --device
```

I'm getting an error of module:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'android-versions'
```

Versions:

```
java -version 
  java version "1.8.0_144"
Android studio Version 2.3.3
ionic -v
2.2.1
cordova -v
6.5.0
```

Answer (score 112):

I found the problem and expect help somebody.
I just run

```
npm install android-versions --save
```

in the project folder and worked.

Comment: does anyone know why this error appears? everything worked well before.

Comment: I was getting the given error after I uninstalled deeplink plugin but by trying this command, the error resolved.

Comment: Seems like this issue appeared to me when upgrading to cordova android version 6.3.0

Comment: For me this appears when running `cordova run android` when cordova android version 6.4.0 is added. if i specifically add android@6.3 it does not show.

Comment: @jabu.hlong how to add android@6.3

Comment: @white-comet `ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0`

Comment: Thank you ! Happened to me after I deleted the apk from my phone

Answer (score 16):

Not sure if this will help some other Ionic developers, but I was getting the same `Error: Cannot find module 'android-versions'` and I fixed it by removing and adding the Android platform again:

```
ionic cordova platform remove android --save
```

And then

```
ionic cordova platform add android --save
```

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is having this issue while using `yarn` and even after adding `android-versions`... it seems that there are differences in `yarn`/`npm` files which break...

I ended up removing my `node_modules` folder, then installing it with `npm` instead of `yarn`. It worked!

Comment: Just ran `yarn add android-versions` and it now works